# CSS Normalize images to 4:3 from assorted ratios

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The image above shows what happens when i fill my bootstrap image gallery with various images. The html looks like this:

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/800x600"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/800x600"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/800x600"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/800x600"></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to make the images normalize to 4:3 without preproccessing them or making them unresponsive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the ratio of an element using the percentage `padding` trick (*which is relative to the width of its container*)

So you must replace the `img` elements with a `div` and set the image as background. Using `background-size:cover` will scale the image to fill its container without stretching. some cropping will occur of-course*)

So your html becomes

```html
<ul class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="img-responsive img-thumbnail ratio-4-3" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and your CSS

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.ratio-4-3{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:url() 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-clip:content-box;
}
.ratio-4-3:before{
    display:block;
    content:"";
    padding-top:75%;
}
```

Demo at http://www.bootply.com/gpetrioli/thU89Ryoer

Comment: Nice. Basically the same as mine, just without using `<img>` tag and unnecessary wrappers.

Comment: @roko the basic idea is the same (*on how to get the ratio*). My example just maintains the bootstrap look (*spacing / borders etc*)

Comment: Exactly! nice 1. I've messed it all. +1

Comment: Thanks! It worked great! If you want to use 16:9 instead of 4:3, padding-top should be 56%

Answer (score -5):

Add this to your css:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about 4:3 ratio, but this will fill each bootstrap container based on what it is defined as

Comment: Are you sure? The `img-responsive` class uses max-width.